# What is the Context column for in String Overrides module?

Tags: 7, string-overrides

With Drupal 7 I have the String Overrides module and there's a coulmn called "Context." I was wondering what this is for?

I was thinking maybe I could type in something like 'user/*' and the string replacement would occur only on 'user/*' pages?

Comment: Is it related to [Localization string contexts](http://localize.drupal.org/node/2109)?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, not much!

It appears to mostly be for D8.

http://drupal.org/node/1477568